# How to avoid stack trace errors due to the use of threading, pika, sklearn and joblib modules

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pickle, joblib, pika

I have a table in the database in which I save SRC(kernel='linear') serialized via pickle.

```
class SVMModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'svm_models'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    uuid: Mapped[str] =  mapped_column(String(90), primary_key=True)
    train_data : Mapped[JSON] =  mapped_column(JSON)
    model_data =  mapped_column(LargeBinary)#In this column I save the serialized object
    
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('company.id'), unique=True)
    company: Mapped[Optional["Company"]] = relationship(back_populates='svm_model')
```

Its loading occurs when a message is sent to the queue via pika and RabbitMQ.
There is an audition and a call from another microservice.

```
start_case_proccess = StartCaseProccess

parameters_upload_case = {
    'upload_process': start_case_proccess.get_file_paths,
    'audio_process': start_audio_process
}

def upload_case_consume():
    consumer = RabbitMQConsumer('localhost', 5672, 'rmquser', 
                                'rmqpass', 'upload_case_procces', parameters_upload_case, 
                                {'connection_name': 'Upload_Case_connection'})
    consumer.connect()
    consumer.start_consuming()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=upload_case_consume, args=())
    t1.start()
```

The error itself occurs when using the load_svm_model function and the Text analyzer class when trying to call self.svm_model = pickle.loads(model_data) in the code below.

```
class TextAnalyser(DbConnect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nlp = spacy.load("ru_core_news_lg")
        self.svm_model = None
    
    def load_svm_model(self, uuid):
        device = self.session_work.query(Devices).filter_by(uuid=uuid).first()
        device_relationship = device.device_relationships
        company_id = device_relationship.company_id
        svm_model = self.session_work.query(SVMModel).filter_by(company_id=company_id).first()
        if svm_model is not None:
            model_data = svm_model.model_data
            self.svm_model = pickle.loads(model_data)
            train_data = json.loads(svm_model.train_data)
            return train_data, model_data
        else:
            return None, None
    
    def assign_label(self, word, train_data, svm_model):
        for label, words in train_data.items():
            if word.lower() in [w.lower() for w in words]:
               return label
        if word.lower() not in [token.lower() for words in train_data.values() for token in words]:
            return "Other"
        return None
    
    def voice_tag(self, text, train_data, svm_model):
        doc = self.nlp(text)
        words = [token.text for token in doc]
        labels = [self.assign_label(word, train_data, svm_model) for word in words]
        return labels
```

Here I call and use this class via pika

```
timestamps = Timestapms()
audio_transcription_process = AudioTranscriptionProcess()
text_analyser = TextAnalyser()

def start_audio_process(message):
    parse_message = json.loads(message)
    audio_path = parse_message["audio_path"]
    device_uuid = parse_message["device_uuid"]
    only_voice_audio_path = timestamps.cut_silence(audio_path)
    words = audio_transcription_process.get_text_variable(audio_path)
    train_data, svm_model = text_analyser.load_svm_model(device_uuid)
    print(only_voice_audio_path, words)
    print(train_data, svm_model)
    for word in words.split():
        labels = text_analyser.voice_tag(word, train_data, svm_model)
        print(f'Text: "{word}"')
        print(f'Labels: {labels}\n')
```

Here is the error itself

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (upload_case_consume):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\app\__main__.py", line 29, in upload_case_consume
    consumer.start_consuming()
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\app\rabbitmq\rabbitmq_consumer.py", line 40, in start_consuming
    self.channel.start_consuming()
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1883, in start_consuming
    self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2044, in _process_data_events
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 851, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 567, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1510, in _dispatch_events
    consumer_info.on_message_callback(self, evt.method,
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\app\rabbitmq\rabbitmq_consumer.py", line 37, in callback
    self.parameters[method.routing_key](body)
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\app\audio_proccess\start_audio_proccess.py", line 18, in start_audio_process
    train_data, svm_model = text_analyser.load_svm_model(device_uuid)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\app\audio_proccess\text_analysis\text_proccess.py", line 21, in load_svm_model
    self.svm_model = pickle.loads(model_data)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import _joblib
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_joblib.py", line 7, in <module>
    import joblib
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .pool import MemmappingPool
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ._memmapping_reducer import get_memmapping_reducers
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .externals.loky.backend import resource_tracker
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\reusable_executor.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .process_executor import ProcessPoolExecutor, EXTRA_QUEUED_CALLS
  File "C:\work_stuff\Gideon-server-proccess\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 88, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures.process import BrokenProcessPool as _BPPException
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 101, in <module>
    threading._register_atexit(_python_exit)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1520, in _register_atexit
    raise RuntimeError("can't register atexit after shutdown")
RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown
```